# Fortran or TeX to Haskell

Tags: haskell, latex

I've symbolically evaluated an integral in FriCAS (Axiom fork) and I want to paste the result as a function in Haskell. However FriCAS can export the output only as TeX, Fortran, MathML, html, texmacs.

Is there a way to parse a TeX formula to Haskell? Any other suggestions?

The formula contains `+ - * / ^ sqrt atan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is specific to FriCAS. One can produce an output as a spad string as described in the [FriCAS mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/fricas-devel/browse_thread/thread/876ba03b42160f49/b9cab60bb3abf561?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=inputform). For me it was

```
unparse(rootSimp((integrate(integrate(halfL - sqrt(r^2-x^2-y^2), y = (sqrt(r^2-halfL^2-x^2))..halfL, "noPole"), x = (sqrt(r^2-2*halfL^2))..halfL,"noPole")) :: Expression(DoubleFloat)) :: INFORM)
```

Spad syntax is very similar to Haskell, however `unparse` represents `sqrt` as `^(1/(2.0))`. Making it `**0.5` is a dirty hack, but after all the speed gain from using an analytic formula instead of 2D numeric integration covers the inefficiency of `**`.

Comment: `**(1/(2.0))` should work just as well; i.e. you should be able to just replace `^` with `**` and all will be well.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing TeX to Haskell seems like it could be painful, especially as it's a Turing-complete language; it seems like the [HaTeX](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX) package has [plans to implement a parser](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaTeX/latest/doc/html/Text-LaTeX-Base-Parser.html) but nothing concrete yet.

If you want to do this for formatting purposes, then I would suggest parsing the MathML with an XML parser (such as [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit) or [hxt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt)) and processing that instead.

The main problem you'll run into is that both TeX and MathML are going to be describing the *appearance* of the formula, rather than its *semantics*.<sup>1</sup> Out of all the formats you've listed, only Fortran will specify the latter, but it's also going to be the hardest to interface with Haskell. The most practical option is probably compiling the Fortran code separately and using it from Haskell with the FFI.

Of course, if the formulae you're dealing with are all as simple as your question suggests, then you might be able to get by with extracting the function from the MathML.

<sup>1</sup> MathML has the ability to describe semantics rather than appearance, but I don't think it's widely-used, and I doubt it's precise enough for a computer to evaluate.